# Windows, Ruby работа с CryptoAPI

Tags: ruby, cryptoapi

Можно ли как то в работать с CryptoAPI в Windows используя Ruby? Под работать понимется чтение списка сертификатов, создание/верификация подписей.
Если да, задайте вектор для размышлений.

Comment: А произвольные виндовые API можно из Ruby дергать?

Comment: можно попробовать через gem win32-api.
https://github.com/cosmo0920/windows-api

Comment: Ну тогда и проблем особых быть не должно - дергайте API в нужном порядке